# Tin created from raster have different profile graphs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, 3d-analyst, raster-conversion, tin

I have created a TIN file from a Raster one, but the profile graph from TIN is different from the Raster. Here I attach a image where in the left is a profile graph from the raster, and on the right is a graph from TIN.

Both the profiles are exactly from the same place.

[image]

Shouldn't the profiles be the same?

For information, to create the TIN I used "Tin to Raster" tool. The parameters are shown in this picture. I did not change anything else!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used Raster to TIN, but judging by the [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-raster-to-tin-works.htm) (which has an image to demonstrate), the triangulation is not performed using all of the nodes in the raster. It uses only enough that the TIN elevation differences are within the Z tolerance. If you'd like a TIN that conforms more closely to the raster, reduce the tolerance.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!! I have just used a Z tolerance of "0.1" and it solved my problem. Now I get the exact same profile as the original raster!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Great. I think the intent of that setting is that you don't really want your TIN to be too dense (otherwise why do it?) so you can experiment with using the largest tolerance that still gives you a result close to what you want...